# Adding text to image and then saving to file

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to add text to an image and then save it. The following actually saves the image but when I try and open it, it says it's not a valid format. It is saved as 'gift-voucher' with no .png extension. Any help appreciated..

```
Dim newimage As bitmap
newimage = system.drawing.Image.FromFile(server.mappath("files/images/gift-voucher.png"))

Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newimage)
Dim myFontLabels as New Font("Arial", 10)
Dim myBrushLabels As New SolidBrush(Color.White)

gr.DrawString("SOLD",myFontLabels, myBrushLabels,10, 190)
newimage.Save("C:\Inetpub\vhosts\onlinecarbooty.com\httpdocs\catalog\images\gift-voucher", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.png)
newimage.Dispose()
```

Comment: You have bigger problems.  That code will not compile under `Option Strict` and it is leaking.  Anything and everything which implements the `Dispose` method ought to be disposed of when you are done with it - which includes the Font and Brush.  A `Using` makes that bloody simple.  When fixed so it compiles, it works fine - who/what says it is not valid?  Without an ext the OS wont know what to do with it.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Sorry, I'm just learning really so used snippets of code from other peple and thought I'd stitched enough together to make this work. Not completely sure what you mean but will keep trying, thank you.

Comment: Never use code you dont understand and be aware that there is lots of bad code on the internet.  When you find something that allegedly solves your problem, look up the methods being used to get an understanding of them. Please read [Ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Ah.. I've just added the dispose() for the brush and font and it's worked champion thank you. I kinda dive straight in and then work out later how things function... bad i know !